# Sinonjs stub not replacing method

Tags: javascript, sinon-chai

Based on an example, I am trying to stub a DB function. But I get "ReferenceError: Database is not defined". Not sure why stub not working! Please help!

Below is my code to be tested -

```js
module.exports = {
   getName : function(name){
       console.log(name);
   },
   setupNewUser : function(info, callback) {
        var user = {
          name: info.name,
          nameUpperCase: info.name.toUpperCase()
        };
        console.log(user.name,user.nameUpperCase)
        try {
          Database.save(user, callback);
        }
        catch(err) {
          callback(err);
        }
      }
}
```

Below is my test -

```js
const expect = require('chai').expect;
const sinon = require('sinon');
const crypto = require('../crypto/crypto');

  describe("test crypto module",function(){
       it("should pass object with correct values to save",function(){
        console.log("save");
        var save = sinon.stub(Database, 'save');
        
        var info = { name: 'test' };
        var expectedUser = {
            name: info.name,
            nameUpperCase: info.name.toUpperCase()
        };

        crypto.setupNewUser(info, function() { });
        sinon.assert.calledWith(save, expectedUser);
        save.restore();


    })
})
```

Comment: Can you show where `Database` is defined in your code? Is it the result of a call to `require` or something else?

Answer (score 0):

In order for this line of your test to run, you need to have defined `Database` in the test code too:

```js
var save = sinon.stub(Database, 'save');
```

Your original code snippet doesn't show how `Database` is defined there. If it is the result of a call to `require`, you might just need to add an equivalent `require` to your test code (because of how node's module cache works):

```js
const Database = require('../path/to/my/db/module');
```

Alternatively, if something more complex is going on like it's the result of a call to some function, you might need to inject it using something like [`proxyquire`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/proxyquire) so that the function returns your stubbed copy. But you'd need to show us the definition of `Database` in your code to know that for certain.

Comment: Ok now I get it that for stubbing I need to add those dependencies as well. I was confused on that part to use dependencies in test or not. Thanks a lot! One more question if you could clarify pls? Can I define the database method something like this var Database = { save : function(arg1,cb){}} in my test and stub it instead of  adding dependency?

Comment: You can do that if you're also injecting `Database` into the code under test somehow. But there's nothing in your example code to suggest you are doing that, so you might need to add it.